# Selenium with Safari 4 and higher

Tags: selenium, safari, selenium-rc

I am new user of Safari. I run automated test scripts in different browsers. I was able to run these with Safari 3.2.2. I know that selenium supports 2 & 3 versions on safari only. Is there any way to exetend these to **4.x** and higher versions of safari.

I tried but only the RC Log is being displayed but the browser is not Instantiated.

Comment: I guess it's not what you want to hear, but as stated [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver), if you go for `WebDriver`, you can have Safari 5+.

Comment: And if you used [`WebDriverBackedSelenium`](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#alternative-back-ends-mixing-webdriver-and-rc-technologies)? That could work with new Safaris, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. I know. This way, there wouldn't be any change in the code needed - apart from the `selenium` instantiation. Give it a try and see yourself whether it works or not: --- `Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(new SafariDriver(), baseUrl);`